# OpenLayers display all markers on screen

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openstreetmap

How do I get all the markers on the map so the users can see all of them?

I have got some amount of markers. I am displaying them on the map.
The center LonLat I get from taking the average of the highest and the lowest numbers of the lon and lat of all my markers.

So I set my map to the center point of all my markers using:

```
map.setCenter(centerLonLat, 8);
```

8 is just a random zooming level. Is there any way to calculate the perfect zooming level so all the markers are displayed in the map?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it working using [zoomToExtent()](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.zoomToExtent)

```
var newBound = OpenLayers.Bounds();
```

For each marker lonlat:

```
newBound.extend(lonLat);
```

Then pass it to the function:

```
map.zoomToExtent(newBound);
```

Comment: should be: var newBound = new OpenLayers.Bounds();

Comment: i used your solution, but does not work because lonLat on marker is null. But i used `getCoords()` and work like this: `bounds.extend(new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(marker.getCoords().lon, marker.getCoords().lat).transform(fromProjection, toProjection));`

Comment: Is this for ol2? What would the ol3 solution be?

Answer (score 11):

A similar way to do it, avoiding a loop, is given by OpenLayers [getDataExtent() function here](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Vector-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.getDataExtent). You need to apply it on the layer containing your markers :

```
var newBound = map.myLayer.getDataExtent();
map.zoomToExtent(newBound);
```

Comment: You could use that as well. But since I am already looping over my markers it would be better to do it in that loop.

Answer (score 10):

This is an old thread, but with changes to OpenLayers I thought I'd post a new solution to this. If you are using a [ol.source.Vector](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html) as your layer source then you can call the following line to fit the map view around your data.

```
map.getView().fit(vectorSource.getExtent());
```

This simultaneously centers the map and sets the zoom so that all of your data is visible at once.